# SwiftUI, multiple shapes with unified shadow?

Tags: swiftui, shadow, shapes

Is there a way in SwiftUI to union two shapes so that they cast a unified shadow. I have tried various combinations and modifiers but don't seem to be able to achieve the look I am after. Any insight would be much appreciated.

```
struct CardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(Color.orange)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 250)
                .zIndex(0)
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.5, to: 1)
                .fill(Color.orange)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .offset(y: -125)
                .zIndex(1)
        }.shadow(color: Color.black, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
    }
}
```

This is what I get, and what I am after ...

[image]

NOTE: `zIndex` was just something I tried, i.e. both shapes having the same `zIndex` etc. its also a quick way to reorder things without having to move the shapes within the container.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo] [image]

```
struct CardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.5, to: 1)
                .fill(Color.orange)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .offset(x: 0, y: 50)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(Color.orange)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 250)
        }
        .compositingGroup()
        .shadow(color: Color.primary, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, this worked perfectly for me in SwiftPlaygrounds 4

Comment: Works great with `.shadow` but not with a gradient applied via `.foregroundStyle`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct answer is @Asperi's `.compositingGroup` as documented here (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/group/3284789-compositinggroup) but I'd like to leave a different working version because there are some use cases where you may not be able or want to use `.compositingGroup`.

So let's look at `.background`, you can copy and paste the code to see in the simulator:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnyShapedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(Color.orange)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 250)
                .zIndex(0)
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.5, to: 1)
                .fill(Color.orange)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .offset(y: -125)
                .zIndex(1)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        AnyShapedView()
        .background(
            AnyShapedView()
            .shadow(color: Color.black, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The output:

[image]

The version above is not the best practice, but nevertheless, try to understand how shapes and cropping work, as in some use cases it might come useful.

Comment: Thank you @punkbit for the taking the time to explain and your insight, every opinion helps, much appreciated. Also The link to compositinggroup in the Apple docs, most helpful, thank you.

Comment: Yeh, your question is actually very useful for a lot of use-cases, so that's why I left that example too :)

Answer (score 0):

Draw the shape:

```swift
struct CustomShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let width = rect.size.width
        let height = rect.size.height
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.89995*width, y: 0.16667*height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.75*width, y: 0.16667*height))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.5*width, y: 0), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.75*width, y: 0.07463*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.63805*width, y: 0))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.25*width, y: 0.16667*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.36195*width, y: 0), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.25*width, y: 0.07463*height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.10005*width, y: 0.16667*height))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.23337*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.0448*width, y: 0.16667*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.19653*height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.93333*height))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.10005*width, y: 1.00003*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.97017*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.0448*width, y: 1.00003*height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.89995*width, y: 1.00003*height))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 0.93333*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.9552*width, y: 1.00003*height), control2: CGPoint(x: width, y: 0.97017*height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 0.23337*height))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.89995*width, y: 0.16667*height), control1: CGPoint(x: width, y: 0.19653*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.9552*width, y: 0.16667*height))
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}
```

And custom color, shadow and size in your parent view:

```
CustomShape()
.fill(.orange)
.shadow(color: Color.primary, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
.frame(width: 300, height: 400)
```